# Reading textareas in datalist within itemcommand

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, datalist

I have a DataList and inside of each item there is an ImageButton that needs to save the contents of an associated textarea.  I normally would pass parameters using the CommandArgument tag, but the text inside the description is very long and I do not want to write it out into the commandargument for all the items being displayed.  Instead, how can I find the ID of the associated textarea so I can save the text the user changes/enters?

I tried passing 'this' into the commandargument but I do not think it is working as it just passes the object for the button and not the whole item.

I realize this seems like a basic question but I've searched for over an hour.  Your help is very appreciated.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="saveDesc" runat="server" AlternateText="Save Image Description" BorderStyle="None" ImageUrl="..\..\images\save.png" CommandArgument='this' CommandName="SaveDescription"  />
<asp:TextBox ID="description" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("description")%>' style="font-weight:bold; width:100%" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="50px"/>
```

There are actually multiple DataLists inside of multiple Accordion views, but I'm not sure if this is relevant to the answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like...

```
protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.CommandName == "SaveDescription")
    {
    DataListItem item = ((DataListItem)((ImageButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
    TextBox description = (TextBox)item.FindControl("description");
    description.Text // return your text 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  This works perfectly without me having to make any changes to my asp markup.  I was not aware that you could get the DataListItem containing the ImageButton in this manner.  This is extremely helpful.  Thanks again!